# How to make horizontal ListView in mvvmCross Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

### I have implemented listView which is vertical

**Here**: https://github.com/devrath/ListView

---

```
 <MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView.MvxRecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation = "horizontal"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/product_view"
            local:MvxBind="ItemsSource MonkeyList; ItemClick clickFunction" />
```

### How to make it Horizontal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Layout Manager](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/recyclerview/#The_Layout_Manager)

> Arranges items in a column that can be scrolled vertically, or in a
>   row that can be scrolled horizontally.

```
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;


var layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(
    context: ApplicationContext, 
    orientation: LinearLayoutManager.Horizontal,
    reverseLayout: false); 
recyclerView.SetLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```